# Find the missing number in unordered Arithmetic Progression

Tags: kdb

Please help me with optimized function to find missing number.

1.Problem

```
q)list1:12 3 6 15 18   /9 is missing number
q)f:{s:asc x; f:first s;e:last s; r where not (r:where 0b,e#((f - 1)#00b),1b) in x}
q)f list1
,9
q)list2:2 8 6 10   /4 is missing number
q)f list2
,4
```

2.Problem
//This is list different above from 2 lists, however just checking with you is it possible to find missing number with common function for these different lists. Because the pattern looks similar in all 3 lists.

```
q)list3:  3  9  1  11  13  5 /missing number 7
```

Comment: Looks like number `3` is missing from `list3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that only single number is missing and sequence start/end are in the list, solution can be simplified as

```
{((0.5*min[x]+max[x])*1+count x) - sum x}
```

Where function

1. Calculates full sequence sum
2. Subtracts sum of available numbers from full sum, which gives missing number